# django tastypie filters returns use format=json

Tags: django, filter, tastypie

I'm having trouble with the tastypie filtering, i followed whats in the documentation but i always get the message:

> Sorry, not implemented yet. Please append "?format=json" to your URL.

I'm not quite sure if I'm missing something:
here's whats under my ModelResource Class:

```
class RequestResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = Request.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'requests'
    excludes = ['done_on', 'requested', 'is_done', 'id']
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
    filtering = {
        'origin': ALL,
        'destination': ALL,
    }
```

I've been following the documentation. and still no results when i enter the url:

> localhost:8000/api/v1/requests/?origin__exact=sample

could you point out what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to tell `tastypie` the format you want your data in. HTTP clients use `Accept` header to tell the web server what kind of data it expects.

For example, my browsers sends following `Accept` header:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

The problem here is that `tastypie` does only implement `application/json`, `application/xml` and whatever HATEOAS uses. If tastypie doesn't find any of these in your `Accept` header it will give the error you describe.

You can override this by using get parameter `format`:

```
localhost:8000/api/v1/requests/?origin__exact=sample&format=json
```

Comment: Just saw this. thanks guys. i figured it out yesterday. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the property TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS

TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS = ['json']

as stated in the documentation [tastypie-default-formats](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#tastypie-default-formats)